# bootstrap dropdown doesn't dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following rendered dropdown (from my rails app):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top topbar" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="/"></a></div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/users/edit">Edit account</a></li>
        <li><a data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" rel="nofollow">Sign out</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Admin<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/users">Users</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Another action</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Another action2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

which displays like this:

[image: partial_menu]

It looks good, but the dropdown does not work. I had it working a while back, but I can't figure out why this doesn't work (the dropdown is just a link to '#'; ie, it won't dropdown).

The log files have nothing. I am not sure where to look to troubleshoot this. How do I fix this?

**EDIT: added js from head tag**
These are the includes:

```
<head>
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ruda:400,900,700" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <title>title</title>
  <meta content="title" name="description">
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/framework_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
  <style type="text/css"></style>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/affix.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/alert.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/button.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/tab.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/transition.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/popover.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap-sprockets.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jetmenu.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/visitors.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param">
  <meta content="***" name="csrf-token">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: If you have included another JavaScript file before dropdown.js or bootstrap.js, perhaps there is an error in that file that is preventing further scripts to execute? There could also be a conflict between the scripts.

Comment: It should be included in my application layout, but I'll check. Wouldn't it not do any of my page with bootstrap though? Or throw an error in the console?

Comment: The page would still display, but it would not do any of the JavaScript required by Bootstrap. If other interactive elements are working, then you probably have the script included.

Do you have jQuery included? It is required for all Bootstrap plugins.

Comment: It seems to be a css problem

Comment: I am inclined to agree with @Daniel that it may be a javascript issue. Can you provide a list of which javascript files the page is using, in order? For instance, the bootstrap script must load after the jquery script to work correctly.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to include all of the JavaScript files separately like that? The bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js files combine all of these files into one. I am also curious as to what the `?body=1` does. Another thing I thought about is that if you are using a Rails library that deals with JavaScript, something may be wrong with that. I am not familiar with Rails, so I'm afraid I couldn't provide much help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Call the dropdowns via JavaScript:

```
 <script>
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    </script>
```

Add this code in your scripts

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/TDrriOiWFB)